# AJAX - Avoiding loading javascript code into an element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, load

**Context**

I am using ajax to check a form filled by a user.

The function performed by the php/javascript loaded after user clicks the submit button ("**External Script**") is that it checks the respective `<input>` fields and if any error is found in a particular `<input>` element, it will (a) load an error message into a pre-prepared `<span>` element  and (b) change the formatting of the invalid `input` element to red.

This  contains:

1. php code that evaluates user's entry and echos a error message (if any error is identified) and
2. javascript that modifies the styling on the `<input>` elements (turns the `<input>` element, in which error was identified by the immediately preceding php code, to red).

**Question**

The problem that I am facing is that along the error message generated by the php part of the External Script also the javascript part gets loaded into the prepared `<span>` element.

I of course want the javascript part of the External Script to be loaded, but not inside the `<span> </span>` element. Is there please a way to achieve this?
Please note that I cannot split the php and the javascript part of the External Script, as the javascript part operates with variables set by the php part (e.g. `var error_empty_message = "<?php echo $error_empty_message;?>";`

**Editted**

MRE:

Base file html:

```
  <form class="form_a" id='registration_form' action="dispatch.php" method="post" enctype ="multipart/form-data">
       <div>
          <label>Contact Email</label>
       </div>
       <div>       
          <input id="mail_email" type= "text" name="email" placeholder="@email" />                        
       </div>
<!-- other similar entries follow -->

    <!-- submit button -->

    <div class='radio_cont'>       
       <button id='mail_submit' type='submit' name='submit' data-popup-open="popup-1">Submit bid</button>
        <button id='reset_f' type='reset'>Reset fields</button>                       
    </div>

 <!-- error message -->

    <div>       
    <span class='form_message'></span>                      
    </div>
```

Loading js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var email = $("#mail_email").val();
    //other input values attributed to vars

    $(".form_message").load("dispatch.php", {
      email: email,
      //other input vars
    });
  })
});
```

*dispatch.php*:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
 $email = $_POST['email'];
   if(empty($email)) 
    {
        echo "<span class='errorek'>Fill in the email please</span>";
        
        $error_empty_email = true;
        

    }

    elseif(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
        echo "<span class='errorek'>Enter a valid email adress</span>";
        $error_email = true;
    }
   
    //other checks follow

}

<script>
$("#mail_email").removeClass("input_error");

var error_empty_email = "<?php echo $error_empty_email;?>";
var error_email = "<?php echo $error_email;?>";

 if(error_email == true || error_empty_email == true) 
    {
        $("#mail_email").addClass("input_error");
    }
//...
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: MRE has been added

Comment: Why does it matter where the JavaScript is loaded?

Comment: For some reason, the javascript code becomes visible on the web page (in the browser). It obviously gets evaluated (it performs the functions that it is supposed to perform) but for some reason it is also projected into the web. I am struggling to figure out what is the reason and the only reason I can think of is that this is because the <script> tag is within a <span> tag.

Comment: *"Please note that I cannot split the php and the javascript part of the External Script, as the javascript part operates with variables set by the php part"* cannot, and won't, aren't synonyms. it's more likely that there's no reason whatsoever for the span to exist, and it exists only because you're sending your form data to the server and receiving the response in a weird, suboptimal way, thus causing further issues like what you're seeing here.

Comment: The reason for the <span> to exists is that the error message returned must be styled properly.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it appears that this is a purely styling issue. For some reason the browser own styling of `script {visibility:none}` has been overwritten.

Entering `script {visibility:none}` (eventually `script {visibility:none!important}`) manually in a linked css file / within a `<style>` tag should solve this issue.

Hopefully this may help someone facing the same issue.